# is this query COUNT is impossible?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I'm facing to very hard pb, i don"t find the way to achieve this, i want count how many occurence is equal to member1(id1) 's occurence , as you see here ,
id2 have 4 equal occurence of id1 and id3 have only 1 egual occurence:

my table test is :

```
id   classement aptitude    A       B   C
1   2440          oui       2       9   1
2   2440          oui       2       9   5
3   1760          oui       1       8   5
4   2440          oui       2       9   1
```

In this exemple ,result expeted should be  :

```
id  count
4     5
2     4
3     1
```

Whats kind of query could achieve it please, is it possible ?!

Comment: dont understand what you want

Comment: `id2 have 4 equal occurence` ? how this ? can you explain it how this 4 comes

Comment: id2 and ID1 have both 4 equal occurence in the row : classement,aptitude,A,B are equal for id1 and id2

Comment: @jess Then in case of Id3 it should be 2

Comment: @Luv : why 2? it will be 0 I think.

Comment: now i get what she want, look like you need a `if` method to check id1.classment = id2.classment , if true , then +1 else 0. then  id1.aptitude =id2.aptitude , if true , then +1 else 0, mean she want check the previous data is it same or not base of number of column id2 have 4 same data of id1 and id3 have 1 same data of id2 . but this method of query need take a while to make it. hope you will do some effort on your query 1st then we trying to help you.

Comment: @Luv i made an error, yes it should be 0 !

Comment: @jess ; Do you wanted to compare all IDs with ID1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select T2.id,
       coalesce((T1.classement=T2.classement),0)+
       coalesce((T1.aptitude=T2.aptitude),0)+
       coalesce((T1.A=T2.A),0)+
       coalesce((T1.B=T2.B),0)+
       coalesce((T1.C=T2.C),0) match_count
from Temp T1
cross join Temp T2
where T1.id = 1 and T2.id <> 1 
order by 2 desc
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/204d4/4).

Comment: @ mark , ur solution seems good , is it possible to count only if fields are NOT NULL ?

Comment: @jess: You can `coalesce` each condition with 0 - see the updated answer.

Comment: @ mark ur answer seems pefect, unfortunatly i have not enough reputation for voting..

Answer (score 0):

**[Here is the Working DEMO of SQLFiddel](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/204d4/1)**

Below is the Sample Query

```
select T1.id,
       (Case T1.classement
         when T2.classement Then 1 Else 0
       End)+
       (Case T1.aptitude
         when T2.aptitude Then 1 Else 0
       End)+
       (Case T1.A
         when T2.A Then 1 Else 0
       End)+
       (Case T1.B
         when T2.B Then 1 Else 0
       End)+
       (Case T1.C
         when T2.C Then 1 Else 0
       End)  Count
  from Temp T1,
      (select * 
         from Temp 
        where id =1) T2
 where T1.id <> 1 
   and (T1.classement = T2.classement
    or T1.aptitude = T2.aptitude
    or T1.A = T2.A
    or T1.B = T2.B
    or T1.C =T2.C)
 order by 2 desc
```

Answer (score -1):

This might work:

```
select a.id,
       length((case when a.aptitude = b.aptitude then '1' else '' end) ||
              (case when a.classement = b.classement then '1' else '' end) ||
              (case when a.A = b.A then '1' else '' end) ||
              (case when a.B = b.B then '1' else '' end) ||
              (case when a.C = b.C then '1' else '' end)) count
  from test a,
       (select *
          from test
         where id = 1) b
 where a.id != 1
```